# Final variables accessibility

Tags: java, static, final

Why can't Final variables be accessed in a static variables.
At the compile time they are simply substituted directly substituted with their values
so, they should be allowed to use even in static methods

why is this restriction???

Comment: Do you want to give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all `final` variables are compile time constants. Only `static final` variables can be substituted by compiler as compile-time constants. `final` modifier in certain cases is only used to ensure [const-correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness).

And `static` methods cannot access non-static variables as those variables can have different values for different instances of the same class.

Answer (score 3):

static = in the class.

final = doesn't change it's value (but it is of each instance if it's not static).

By examply you can do:

```
public class Weird
{
private static long number = System.getTimeInMilis();
private final long created = System.getTimeInMilis();
}
```

Each time you create a Weird object it will contain a different value for created.

But the value of Weird.number will be the time when the class was loaded.

Comment: A more real example: you can create a "private final list = new ArrayList<...>" and you will not change the reference to the list but the list can add objects when you want.

Comment: ...does not change the value *after assignment*.  This is compiler enforced, not jvm enforced

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking why a `static` method cannot access a `final` instance variable (on the [incorrect] assumption that final member variables are always set to literal or constant values in the code), its because different instances of a class can have different values for the same `final` instance variable (which can be set, for example, via the constructor).  A `static` method has no knowledge of any particular instance of the class, and could only access `static final` variables.